# how to check if service-worker cached all files from the manifest

Tags: vuejs3, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to understand the PWA cache behavior. the application is developed in vue3/cli with the pwa plugin.

As expected, the "service-worker.js.map" is created during the build, in which all urls are neatly present in an array, perfect!

I would like to have the application check if all files are cached.

I loaded some files "manually" into a cache "testcache" for the test. in Google Dev > Application > Cache Storage the cache is then called "testcache - https://domainname

the cache that is filled via serviceworker is then called
"vue-pwa-test-precache-v2-https://domainname - https://domainname"

Now I have the special case that I need a complete offline app. User pulls PWA APP and goes to an offline area.

How can I determine whether all files are already in the cache via service-worker? How can I determine the name of the cache. is the name always appended with t-precache-v2-https://domainname - https://domainname?

I could display an animation while the user has to wait.